# The different meanings of に対して

Tags: grammar

に対して is generally used with the sense of "in contrast to" or "in regard to/ toward to"; however I never understood if the difference can only be infered by the context or there is a difference in patter. Usually when it has the meaning of "in opposition to" it seems that is preceded by の, like in　のに対して, but I am not sure if it is a rule or just a coincidence.

In the following sentences I believe it means "in contrast":

外遊びが好きな長男のに対して、次男は家の中で遊ぶことが好きだ。

昨日は大阪では大雨だったのに対して、東京はいい天気だった。

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a specific patter for when に対して means "in contrast to" or "in regard to/ toward to", or the difference in meaning must be understood by reading the passage as a whole.

Comment: Could you provide some examples that use「に対して」where you think the implication of *contrast* is stronger than that of *in regard to* or vice versa? Interesting question!

Comment: の in のに対して is a nominalizer to transform whatever comes before that is not a noun to a noun so that it connects to に, regardless of this phrase.

Comment: I provided two examples so to make clear my message.

Comment: I think what OP is asking is: What is the difference between Nounに対して and Nounのに対して. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The main concept of 「対する」 is that two things face each other, and I think the meaning is derived metaphorically.

When the two things are of opposite nature, the English translation of "in opposition to" or "in contrast" fit the context (rain in Osaka vs. sunny in Tokyo in your sample). When the two things are in subject-object relation or source-target relation (question/answer in 「質問に対する答え」), the translation can be "in regard to".